# Measure if path is set as Clipping path

Tags: imagemagick, photoshop, tiff, clipping, identify

Our company receives thousands of images every year, that has to be saved in exactly the correct way. 
Up till now this has been done by hand by Agencies, but our Indesign server has started to crash when a tiff image has a path but no set clipping path.

I wish to find a way to measure if the clipping path has been set using a tool like exiftool or ImageMagick.

Does anyone have  a way to determine if the clipping path has been set ?

I will be checking using Java, so any commandline tool will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ImageMagick's Identify command line tool with option -verbose will output information about any clipping path in the image.